# java.util.Date Calculate difference in days

Tags: java, date, dst, java-time, days

I tried to calculate the difference between two dates and I noticed one thing. When calculating only the days, the start of daylight saving time is included in the interval, so the result will be shorter with 1 day.

To obtain accurate results, the value of hours also must be considered.

For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date dfrom = format.parse("03-29-2015");
Date dto = format.parse("03-30-2015");
long diff = dto.getTime() - dfrom.getTime();
System.out.println(diff);
System.out.println("Days: "+diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
System.out.println("Hours: "+diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24);
```

Output:

```
82800000
Days: 0
Hours: 23
```

Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Can you use java.time (Java 8) or Joda Time instead? Both will make this a *lot* simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: The root cause is your assumption in line 6 that every day has 24 hours, when you already know that the interval you are measuring contains a day that is only 23 hours long.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh yes a better solution there is!

Stop using the outmoded `java.util.Date` class and embrace the power of the [java.time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). Specifically, the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), and [`ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) classes.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("03-29-2015", formatter);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("03-30-2015", formatter);
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
System.out.println(days); // prints 1
```