# Current file is older than a X time or not

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, nio

I want to check if the file creation is older than a certain time (days). So far, this is how i got the file creation time.

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
long fileCreationTime = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
```

now I want to check if this file was created before `X` number of days or not. How would i go about it. I am trying to look into LocalDateTime but kind a lost.

P.S: I don't want to use any external library.

Comment: What's confusing you about `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904886/java-util-date-calculate-difference-in-day or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
long numberOfDays = 5L;
if (attr.creationTime().toInstant().isBefore(
        Instant.now().minus(numberOfDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    )
) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to check if the `file` is older than X number of months, you can proceed as next:

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long numberOfMonths = 5L;
if (attr.creationTime().toInstant().isBefore(
        dt.minus(numberOfMonths, ChronoUnit.MONTHS).toInstant(zdt.getOffset())
    )
) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but if i try `Instant now = Instant.now().minus(6L, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);` it gives me exception that `Usupported Unit: Months`. I want to figure out if the `file` is older than X number of months.

Comment: in your question is x number of days

Comment: I updated my answer to cover the months, please check again